# Why drawArc method in android canvas does't provide smooth circle with paint style as STROKE?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas, android-custom-view, custom-view

I have been working to create gauges chart in android with custom view. 
Initially I try to draw a semicircle, it works fine. When i try to split the content as 45 degree with one colour and another arc another colour, There is an inconsistency (a small white space) between the two arc.
I used to draw two arc with paint style as STROKE. Radius value and bounds is not changed in both cases. How to remove the white space which lies between two arc?

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(radius * 0.3f);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawArc(contentRect, 180, 45, false, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc(contentRect, 225, 135, false, paint);
}
```

[image]